# Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in Url parameter Asp.Net Web form server-side code that's generating the form

Tags: asp.net, xss

We have Legacy Asp.Net Web form Web application and it falls under Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in Url parameter for server-side code server-side code that's generating the form, to show how the 1234 is making its way from querystring to form action.

Below are the steps:

For example let say web application URL is : https://example.com/default.aspx.

Now user type in browser https://example.com/default.aspx/1234 and press enter key, which falls under Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in Url parameter.

When I inspect the HTML tags, form action url is changed to  ./1234 as below:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" name="aspnetForm"
      method="post" action="./1234" 
      onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();">
```

I have tried to check value of Request.QueryString, but not able to get value 1234.

Please advise what will be fix and where to apply. Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you echoing out the `1234` directly in the page somewhere without sanitising/escaping it?  If so, that's probably what's triggering the alert - eg if you try `default.aspx/<script>alert('oops')</script>` and you see the alert on your page, that's classic reflected XSS

Comment: Thank you, James. Yes there is not sanitizing/ escaping. I do not know where and how to escaping. If possible can you show sample code. Thank you.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the server-side code that's generating the form, to show how the `1234` is making its way from querystring to form action (and perhaps the reasoning for it needing to do so?) - it'll help give a better, more direct answer.

Comment: Edited with suggested text. Thanks James.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to edit that particular text into the question, rather I meant you should add your actual code to the question.

Comment: Sorry, But this is normal Web Form with Master page. Where Master page has form tag. and ContentPlaceHolder. Here is the sample Master page. :
%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="site.master.vb" Inherits="site" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />